# Problem animation boat floating on ocean, in THREE JS

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js

I have a project to do in THREE JS in WEBGL and I'm blocking. I would like to make a boat that floats on water. Here my boat should follow the waves created by my ocean function as follows:

```
const gsize = 1000;
                    const res = 1024;
                    const gres = res / 2;
                    const origx = - gsize/2;
                    const origz = - gsize/2;
                    this.ms_Ocean = new Ocean( this._threejs, this._camera, this._scene,
                        {
                            USE_HALF_FLOAT: false,
                            INITIAL_SIZE: 256.0,
                            INITIAL_WIND: [ 10.0, 10.0 ],
                            INITIAL_CHOPPINESS: 1.5,
                            CLEAR_COLOR: [ 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0 ],
                            GEOMETRY_ORIGIN: [ origx, origz ],
                            SUN_DIRECTION: [ - 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 ],
                            OCEAN_COLOR: new THREE.Vector3( 0.004, 0.016, 0.047 ),
                            SKY_COLOR: new THREE.Vector3( 3.2, 9.6, 12.8 ),
                            EXPOSURE: 0.35,
                            GEOMETRY_RESOLUTION: gres,
                            GEOMETRY_SIZE: gsize,
                            RESOLUTION: res
                        } );
    this.ms_Ocean.materialOcean.uniforms[ "u_projectionMatrix" ] = { value: this._camera.projectionMatrix };
    this.ms_Ocean.materialOcean.uniforms[ "u_viewMatrix" ] = { value: this._camera.matrixWorldInverse };
    this.ms_Ocean.materialOcean.uniforms[ "u_cameraPosition" ] = { value: this._camera.position };
    this._scene.add( this.ms_Ocean.oceanMesh );
```

My question is: How do I follow the movement of the waves? Just like if I had a plan maybe.
The boat must have a floating effect on the water.

I have done a lot of research but I can't really find anything that suits me. If anyone has any idea how I can do this. Thank you !

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fma9B.jpg)

Comment: Maybe this demo can point you in the right direction: https://threejs.org/examples/?#webgl_gpgpu_water notice how the yellow balls float on the water.

Comment: I saw this example, but it uses a plane but I don't have a plane but an Ocean type object that's why it's complex!